# What do the model numbers in Harmonic Drive gear drives represent?

Tags: actuator, gearing

According to [one of their brochures](http://www.harmonicdrive.net/_hd/content/catalogs/pdf/csf-csg-catalog.pdf), Harmonic Drive numbers their models with numbers like 8, 11, 14, 17, etc.

I noticed that Chinese suppliers like Laifaul have a similar numbering scheme, though it is not clear to me that they correspond to the same specs that that the Harmonic models do.

Do these numbers have some physical significance?  Torque?  Dimension?  Or are they just some legacy model numbering scheme?

Answer (score 1):

It is the pitch diameter of the flex spline in inches/10. You can see it used it their equations for thrust force on the wave generator.